# ./configure doesn't make makefile

Tags: 12.04, command-line, make, configure

I'm trying to install [GTKTerm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gtkterm/?source=typ_redirect)

on my 12.04 LTS distribution.
I read the INSTALL file for install the software. 
First I run `./configure`, no errors are shown, but there is not the makefile, so when I run `make`, I receive this error `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`
Here the output of `./configure`

```
loading cache ./config.cache
checking for a BSD compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking whether make sets ${MAKE}... yes
checking for working aclocal-1.4... missing
checking for working autoconf... missing
checking for working automake-1.4... missing
checking for working autoheader... missing
checking for working makeinfo... missing
checking for strerror in -lcposix... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) works... yes
checking whether the C compiler (gcc  ) is a cross-compiler... no
checking whether we are using GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for Cygwin environment... no
checking for mingw32 environment... no
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for ld used by GCC... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for object suffix... o
checking for executable suffix... no
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output... ok
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.lo... yes
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking whether the linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
creating libtool
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for gtk+-2.0 gdk-2.0...
```

How can I solve?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you font want to: `sudo apt-get install gtkterm`?

Comment: I would like try to install the program going through the `./configure` method so I learn something new.

Comment: Add the full output of `./configure` to your question.

Comment: This is a dependency issue. You need to install al the dependencies needed before you can ./configure, see my edit below.

Comment: That isn't the full output of `./configure`.

Comment: @linofex You should edit the title of the question to make it more informative for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily install GTKTerm from the terminal using `sudo apt-get install gtkterm`.

**EDIT**

What you are looking at is a dependency problem(i.e. see lines like `aclocal-1.4... missing`). You need to install all dependencies which are required before for you can compile GTKTerm, to install this dependencies, use this:

`sudo apt-get build-dep gtkterm`

Once you have done this, you should be able to run `./configure` without any problems.

Answer (score -1):

`make` takes a makefile as input. Makefile usually is named `makefile` or `Makefile`. The configue command should generate a makefile, so that `make` could be in turn executed. Check if a makefile has been generated under your working directory.

Comment: This is the problem, after `./configure` there isn't the makefile. The are only two makefile in the folder (since before the ./configure):
`Makefile.am` and `Makefile.in`

Comment: are you in `root` ?

Comment: Yes, I ran the commando with `sudo`

Comment: Did you install the all dependencies? GtkTerm has a few dependencies-

`Gtk+3.0 (version 3.12 or higher)`
`vte (version 0.40 or higher)`
`intltool (version 0.40.0 or higher)`

Comment: No, how can I install them?

Comment: You have to install each dependencies manually. :)

Comment: Or you can look at my edit to see how to do that :).

Comment: Agree with Tshilidzi . Look at his answer. That's the best option for solving this problem